# Which View Switcher control is this in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

Can anybody tell me which View Switcher Control is this in below image.?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are probably tabs.
http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html

Please make sure to do a bit of research before posting on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thankx mate. i did my research before posting on StackOverflow.